# How can I get wide angle camera id in my android app?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2, wide-angle

I am using camera 2 api in my android project and I need to record and capture image using wide angle lens. I am not able to find any solution to this

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where have you been getting your information? What errors did you get when you tried any of it? Give some context for people to be able to help you better. Cheers!

Comment: Hi

I am using Camera 2 api and tried to fetch the camera id's using cameraManager.getCameraIdList(), it returns only two camera id's 0 and 1. Wide angle lens has camera Id 2. 

I tried using characteristics.getPhysicalCameraIds() and it returns nothing. 

Any help will be much much appreciated